# How to ssh through a SOCKS proxy when the ssh requires an existing ProxyCommand to work

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, proxy, socks-proxy

I've got some hosts that I can ssh to using a ProxyCommand in my ssh config file.  For example:

```
Host vm1
    ProxyCommand ssh -q -l owl -W vm1:22 gateway.example.com
    User owl

Host gateway.example.com
    HostName gateway.example.com
    User owl
    Controlmaster auto
```

It has been a while since I set it up, so I don't recall why I needed the second entry, or if in fact it's needed for this purpose or something else.

On my remote machine I normally type `ssh vm1` and it connects to the host vm1 going through the machine `gateway.example.com` (as vm1 is behind a firewall at the gateway and isn't visible otherwise).  It actually gets a bit more complicated than this because on top of this because from vm1 there is another connection made to facilitate an RDP connect locally to a second VM, so locally the command looks something like this:

```
ssh -N -f -M -S /tmp/rdp-vm2.sock -L4001:vm2:3389 vm1
```

And then locally the RDP client connects to 127.0.0.1:4001.  The socket is because this is part of a script which automatically starts the RDP client and kills the connection when the RDP connection closes.

However, I need this to work when I am behind a SOCKS proxy locally. (This is at 192.168.1.1 port 8000.)  I am able to connect locally to the gateway (e.g. `ssh gateway.example.com`) by adding the following line to the `gateway.example.com` section of my ssh config file:

```
ProxyCommand nc -X 5 -x 192.168.1.1:8000 %h %p
```

But testing the next hop (`ssh vm1`) fails:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I have read that using nc is somewhat obsoleted for normal proxying, and I'm assuming I just need to replace my ProxyCommand to `gateway.example.com` with something using ssh with the `-W` option, but it's unclear to me what to replace it with when I'm using a SOCKS proxy specifically.

Answer (score 0):

The ordering of the `ProxyCommand` is important.  It needs to be added as the first line under the `gateway.example.com` host, not the last.

So change it to look like this:

```
Host gateway.example.com
    ProxyCommand nc -X 5 -x 192.168.1.1:8000 %h %p
    HostName gateway.example.com
    User owl
    Controlmaster auto
```